# There is Change in classification total area after Exporting and reclassifying it from **Google Earth Engine** to ArcMap

Tags: arcmap, google-earth-engine, area, classification

I have done **classification** of 6 classes in google earth engine on an available forest mask that has an area of about **2493 sq. km**. The forest mask basically uploaded to Google Earth Engine and satellite imagery clipped on it for classification purposes. After classification analysis, I have exported the classified image to ArcMap and performed basic analysis e.g(mosaicking, projection to the required coordinate system, and reclassification). After reclassification, I have computed the area of each class and total it which is **2196 sq. km** it variate **296 sq km** from the original area. I have done the same procedure many times but got the same issue. I don't know where I have done wrong while analyzing. If anyone goes through the same issue or knows how we can check it so that area should be the same as the mask used.
For clarification, I am attaching screenshots. eq3 is the original area and the table is computed one.
[image: orinal area of the forest mask]
[image: area gets after reclassification]

Comment: If the grid of the mask and what you are masking isn't matching completely, GEE will do a what they call 'weighted' area calculation. That means, if the mask overlaps a pixel by 20%, Earth Engine will also count 20% of it's area. ArcGIS might handle that differently. Also, depending on your reprojection, the area calculations might change.

Comment: Then how I should overcome this problem? By removing the mask there are huge effects on results on the other hand I am using the same data set which the mask has prepared on. What are the ways to at least get close to the total area of the mask any suggestion?

Comment: You are probably using a too-large study scale when measuring the total area in GEE. Larger scales are useful to accelerate the time it takes to run, but there is a loss in resolution which may alter the end result (such as area calculation). Try reducing the scale and see if the value is closer to the ArcGIS one.